# Why would I be able unable to access a website from my local network when the site is widely available?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

Requests to several websites on Media Temple's Grid Server (shared hosting; more than one account) are timing out for me today. Everything was fine earlier this morning, and for no apparent reason these URLs are timing out in the browser, via FTP client, and SSH.

Clues/notes:

- the websites are up, and I can access them from other networks (verified with support and on 4G cell)
- it's not etc/hosts or machine-specific issues; reproduced the timeouts on three different devices on my local network
- all tested ports time out: 80, 22, 443
- applications tested: Chrome+Safari+Terminal Mac (two different machines), Chrome+Safari iOS7
- I changed our router from its default DNS to [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/), with no change in behavior
- a local traceroute to any given site will work just fine, showing a full/quick/healthy path to the server
- there is no VPN, proxy, firewall, sophisticated routing, or tomfoolery in place; router+ethernet to building rack to microwave equipment on roof
- following tony roth's suggestion, `nslookup foo.com` prints the exact same result from within and without my local network
- I've flushed my DNS and restarted my primary machine several times with my fingers crossed

Have I missed something obvious? I'm not sure what to do when the traceroute looks normal but I'm hopelessly unable to access these servers that are clearly up and running.

Comment: so from the external clients if you do an "nslookup yourwebsite" does it appear different (as in different ip address(s))then from you internal network?

Comment: No, the lookup prints the exact same result; the IP addresses match when checked locally and externally.

Comment: I'm just assuming nobody cranked up a firewall, but maybe thats not a good assumption.

Comment: Good assumption. I have direct control over the router, and there are only three people working in this office – nothing has changed on our local network, though I can't speak for the building or beyond.

Comment: and does it work if you use an IP address instead of DNS, if this is possible?

Comment: can you check the logs on your router, better yet with only 3 people can you just bounce the router?

Comment: @boburob: I don't have an IP to test directly since it's a shared host, but I can ping the shared IP just fine, and editing my etc/hosts makes no difference.

Comment: what is in your hosts file, since you have a functioning dns system I'd leave it blank.

Comment: @tonyroth: Not having a device to easily get to the ethernet cable, I put the router in bridge mode and the problem has gone away. The hosts file just contains mostly.dev domains to be used for local development.

Comment: @tonyroth: You ultimately led me to a fix, but I'd feel like a douche creating and accepting my own answer. Would you mind? Ultimately it was a Double NAT problem.

Comment: has it been working in bridge mode then suddenly just quit or did you just make the change today?

Comment: @tonyroth: It has been working fine for a little more than a month in DHCP+NAT mode, and I just made this switch to Bridge mode today and those specific sites are suddenly back.